# CMake Error Failed to run MSBuild command

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

I am very new to CMake and try to build a minimum CMake file on Windows where I have installed Visual Studio 17 and 19. The C++ code is the bare minimum main.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The CMakeLists.txt file is also the minimum:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(hello)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
```

When I run the CMake on the command line, I get this error and I do not know how to resolve it:

```
C:\SampleProject\build>cmake ./../src
-- Building for: Visual Studio 15 2017
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  Failed to run MSBuild command:

    MSBuild.exe

  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

    The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Instead of typing `cmake ./../src` does typing msbuild.exe give you an "msbuild.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: You have to run `cmake` from a "*x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019*" (it's a shortcut that Visual Studio installs in the Start Menu). Might also give Ninja a try, it's much easier to use with CMake than MSBuild.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I could not run the MSBuild on command line and when I run the x64 Native tools for VS 2017 it worked!

Comment: I almost always run CMake from a Visual Studio command prompt with the path and environment variables setup. Although for me this is partly due to having multiple compilers installed and multiple build trees for a work environment.

Answer (score 0):

By default VC++ tools aren't on the PATH, they are added to the PATH by the `vcvarsall.bat` script.

Run `cmake` from a "***x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019***" (it's a shortcut to `vcvarsall.bat` that Visual Studio installs in the Start Menu).

---

Bonus note:

When not using **Visual Studio** integration, you might want to consider [Ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) as the alternative build system to MSBuild. It's more CMake-friendly because it doesn't require the Debug/Release duality of configuration (which is the source of headache when working with CMake).

1. Download [ninja.exe](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/releases), add it to the PATH
2. Use the Ninja CMake generator: `cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..`
3. Enjoy easy and fast builds using the `ninja` command.
4. To build a Release version, re-run cmake with `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` (so this works very much the same as on other platforms, e.g. Linux).

Ninja also integrates well with the VSCode [CMake extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools) (note: VSCode != VS).